# ¿Como convertir en exe archivos de pyqt5?

Tags: pyqt5

estoy intentando convertir en exe una interfaz que hice con pyqt5, contiene varias imágenes. Para la lógica del programa la llamo como archivo de .ui en python. Al tratar de convertirlo a exe con pyinstaller me salen todos los archivos pero al abrir el exe sale el error de la imagen, no sé en que estoy fallando, porfas su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

me sale otro error, lo estoy ahora haciendo con cx_freeze pero me sigue saliendo este error, no sé en que estoy fallando
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de instalar el paquete pkgutil antes de empaquetar tu proyecto. Puedes usar  `pip install pkgutil`
Es posible que el error sea dado por la falta de ese modulo.